# create a table template and render data from form inputs

Tags: backbone.js

The form input field have parameters X and Y. If I select the operator (add, subtract, multiply or divide) the result should be displayed in the result area. All these values should be dynamically transferred to the table view using Backbone.js. Since I started learning the core information, can somebody suggest how to create a dynamic view in a table by Backbone.js and how to collect data from the form inputs?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Math Function</title>
    <script src="Script/jquerylibrary.js"></script>
    <script src="Script/Underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="Script/Backbonelibrary.js"></script>
    <script src="JavaScript/mathFunction.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/mathFunction.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label>Enter Value of X :</label>
        <input type="text" id="parameter1">
        <label>Enter Value of Y :</label>
        <input type="text" id="parameter2">
        <select>
            <option>Add</option>
            <option>Subtract</option>
            <option>Multiply</option>
            <option>Divide</option>
        </select>
        <label>Result of the fucntion :</label>
        <input type="text" id="Result">
    </form>
    <br>
    <hr/>
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Parameter X</th>
                    <th>Parameter Y</th>
                    <th>Operator</th>
                    <th>Result</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="data">
                <tr>
                    <td>dummy</td>
                    <td>dummy</td>
                    <td>dummy</td>
                    <td>dummy</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/7k34p/) of a dynamic view in a table with Backbone :

```
var Row = Backbone.View.extend({... // view that represents a row in the table

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({... // view that interact with the inputs
```